# Interpreting Bytebuffer that contains different data types

Tags: java

I have a Bytebuffer that contains characters and letters. If I convert it as a CharBuffer, number values will be displayed as strange symbols. How can I make sure they are interpreted as numbers?

```
//p is a Bytebuffer

CharBuffer cb = p.asCharBuffer();
String result = "";
String byteResult ="";

while (p.hasRemaining()) {           
     char c = cb.get();
     result = result.concat("" + c);

     byte b = p.get();
     byteResult =byteResult.concat(""+b);*/         
}

System.out.println("char Inhalt: " + result);
System.out.println("byte Inhalt: " + byteResult);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're trying to read ASCII or UTF-8 text from a stream, a `CharBuffer` likely isn't what you want as Java chars are UTF-16 and thus 2+ bytes each. Have you considered using an [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) and specifying the charset?

Comment: What do you see for `byteResult`?